# Division in JavaScript giving undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

Im trying to calculate the time between when a user starts typing and when they reach the end. So I have named two constants both using the `Date.now();` function. Whenever I run the program it always gives the error : `ReferenceError: start is not defined at HTMLInputElement.element.onkeyup (/main.js:86:16)` The code is below:

Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("boch");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("bocho").click();
  }
});


var element = document.querySelector("#boch");

element.onkeyup = function () {
  var value = element.value;

   if (value.includes("m")) {
     let start = Date.now();
  } 

  if (value.includes("man")) {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become")) {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as")) {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and")) {
    document.getElementById('word-4').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-4').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through")) {
    document.getElementById('word-5').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-5').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find")) {
    document.getElementById('word-6').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-6').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would")) {
    document.getElementById('word-7').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-7').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here")) {
    document.getElementById('word-8').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-8').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and")) {
    document.getElementById('word-9').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-9').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and before")) {
    document.getElementById('word-10').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-10').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

   if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and before")) {
     let end = Date.now();
 
  }
  let millis = start/end;

  console.log(`seconds elapsed = ${Math.floor(millis / 1000)}`);


}
```

Html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<h1>
   <span id="word-1">man</span> <span id="word-2">become</span> <span id="word-3">as</span>
   <span id="word-4">and</span> <span id="word-5">through</span> <span id="word-6">find</span> <span id="word-7">would</span> <span id="word-8">here</span> <span id="word-9">and</span> <span id="word-10">before</span>
</h1>

<input type="text" id="boch" autocomplete="off">

        </div>
        <div id="typing-area">

      <button id="bocho" onclick="document.getElementById('boch').value = ''">Enter</button>

</html>




<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Either use `var` to declare the variable or move it outside the `if` block.

Comment: See [*What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var?r=SearchResults&s=1|2868.1953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have declared the variable 'start' is not in the same scope as when it is being used. This means that

```
let millis = start/end;
```

is unable to see start.

You need to change let to be var. This way the scope is not restricted in the same way

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the variable *start* is **undefined** in your *element.onkeyup*, that means, in your function. If the variable doesn't exist, is impossible to do any calc with it.

Basicly, you have a **scope problem**, the variables (let and const) exists only in the local that they are declared, so the *start* exist only in one `if(){}`. The same with the variable *end*.

To fixed it, the ideal is declare the variables (*start* and *end*) in the top, before your `if's`, together to the *value*.